# How to show products in Volusion when inserted through Volusion API

Tags: php, api, curl, volusion

I am importing the products through the Volusion API, the products are inserted but not shown on the front-end of my store.

Anyone who know that how to show the products in front-end.

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: check product element must be thus: `<HideProduct>N</HideProduct>`

Comment: <HideProduct/> as like this in my code.

Comment: still not work bro

Comment: You keep asking the same or similar questions and provide little or no information to help. With that said I would suggest rebuilding the search index located in the http://www.yoursiteurl.com/admin/Upgrade_Maintenance.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the category to the product then it will be shown on the front-end. In Volusion categories are virtual and not added when adding the product. you have to assign the categories in a another API call or can manually assign the category from back-end.